# is there a way in sql to scan a column by a group, and then return a value if specifications are met?

Tags: sql-server

I have something like below. By `ID`, I want to scan within it and return specific values. For example ID=2 has values a and b, so I want to create another column producing `a/b'.

I feel like I can use case when, but not sure how to move forward. sorry, new to sql

```
val ID  want 
 a   2   a/b
 a   2   a/b
 b   2   a/b
 c   1   c
 c   1   c
 a   3   a
 a   3   a
```

Comment: Please learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15